# Listview FindItemWithText method cannot find Subitem Text with special characters

Tags: powershell, listview, search, character

I Created a listview $ListViewY and populated it with $ListviewitemY. Added special characters to Text of some SubItems.
FindItemWithText cannot find the special characters. Any way to make it work ?

PS C:\Users> $Arrow = (Invoke-Expression ("[char]" + "0x25c0"))

PS C:\Users> $Arrow

◀

PS C:\Users> $ListviewitemY[0].SubItems[0].Text = '44' + (Invoke-Expression ("[char]" + "0x25c0"))

PS C:\Users> $ListviewitemY[0].SubItems[0].Text

44◀

## Following Works..

If ($ListviewitemY[0].SubItems[0].Text -match $Arrow){ $x = 'Found it'}

## Following does not. FindItemWithText cannot find it..

$ListViewItemSingle = $ListViewY.FindItemWithText($Arrow, $true, 0, $true)

If ($ListViewItemSingle){ $y = 'Found it'}

Any way to make FindItemWithText work in this case ?